# Tuning an ancient carbureted Honda motorcycle

Tags: honda, motorcycle, carburetor, tuning, backfire

I was in an accident recently.  Tboned by a minivan at an intersection.  Totaled my nice bike.

My buddy gave me an old rust bucket he had laying around just to get me to work for a few weeks until I get something else.

It's a Honda 600cc, early 90s.  Carbureted.  I replaced the battery but it's not holding a charge.  It's backfiring all the time.  And it accelerates insanely slowly, and pretty much sounds like it's going to fall apart if you give it the evil eye.

I'm going to replace the chain this weekend and take it apart to see where I can give it some love without really dumping any money into it.

Tips?  Not sure what to do about the backfire or battery issues.

Comment: Does opening the choke reduce the backfire?

Comment: Is this a multi-cylinder bike with one carb per cylinder?

Comment: Haha - I realized you threw "ancient" and "early 90's" into the mix ... I'm from the mid-60's ... what does that make me ;-)

Comment: I thought the same thing when I wrote it.. but as it compares to sports bikes, it just feels ancient.  First time I've ever ridden a carburated bike that I had to switch the fuel line on and off every time.  I suspect the rust is crucial to keeping the whole thing in 1 piece at this point.  ;)

Comment: Trust me switching on fuel line on a carb bike is the least thing you could be worried about. Thank your gods that the jets are fine.

Comment: If you can give the exact model and year I can tell you how to take the backfire out of that bike.  I'm thinking it's an XL or an XR.

Comment: Can you provide the model and year please?  If you are unsure you can use a VIN decoder to nail it down.

Answer (score 2):

For you backfire check the following components.

- Clean Spak plugs
- Clean carb
- Clean air filter
- If the other two dont work then there might be issue with valve seating, not 100% sure but there are chances since its old vehicle.

For your battery issue.

- [Check](http://www.instructables.com/id/Testing-batteries-with-multimeter/) check the alternator/rectifier

Comment: The battery is new (just replaced)